# OnGetFilePath event not firing

Tags: javascript, twain, dynamic-web-twain

After a user has scanned a document - I would like to allow them to select a location to save the file, save the file, and finally return the path to the file they have just saved.

I am trying to use the "[OnGetFilePath](https://developer.dynamsoft.com/dwt/api-reference/loading-saving/ongetfilepath)" event but it's not working.

JS Code is here:

```
var DWObject;

Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.AutoLoad = false;
Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.RegisterEvent('OnWebTwainReady', Dynamsoft_OnReady);


function LoadEnv() {
    Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.Load();
}

function Dynamsoft_OnReady() {
    DWObject = Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.GetWebTwain('dwtcontrolContainer');

    if (DWObject) {

        DWObject.IfShowFileDialog = true;
        DWObject.RegisterEvent('OnGetFilePath', OnGetFilePath); 

        DWObject.SelectSource(function () {
            DWObject.OpenSource();
            DWObject.IfDisableSourceAfterAcquire = true;
            DWObject.AcquireImage(OnAcquireImageSuccess, OnAcquireImageFailure);
        }, function () {
            console.log('SelectSource failed!');
        });
    }
}

function OnAcquireImageSuccess() {
    console.log('Successfully aquired image');
    SavePDF();
    DWObject.CloseSource();
}

//File saved to disk successfully 
function SavePDF() {
    DWObject.SaveAsPDF('file.pdf');
}

//Not Fired
function OnGetFilePath(bSave, filesCount, index, path, filename) {
    console.log("File Path!");
}
```

Comment: Like this?  `DWObject.RegisterEvent('OnGetFilePath', function () { console.log('OnGetFilePath'); }); ` Afraid this doesn't work either

Comment: No, exactly as the example - DWObject.RegisterEvent('OnGetFilePath', function(bSave, filesCount, index, path, filename){ console.log('OnGetFilePath'); });

Comment: No luck with that I'm afraid.

Comment: According to their documentation, that event only gets fired for 2 things. Your code above does not satisfy those. See the answer I added that shows how to test that event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did and I think it will help you.

- I downloaded the sample code - https://demo.dynamsoft.com/DWT/online_demo_scan.aspx
- I added a button next to the Scan button on online_demo_scan.html

  <input id="btnTest" value="TEST" type="button" onclick="DWObject.ShowFileDialog(false, 'JPG,PNG,TIF', 0, '', '', true, true, 0);"/>
- I added an alert to Dynamsoft_OnGetFilePath in online_demo_operation.js

  function Dynamsoft_OnGetFilePath(bSave, count, index, path, name) {
      alert('OnGetFilePath event fired!');
  }

And the event does fire when I click the button.

According to the documentation

> This event is triggered when 1. the ShowFileDialog method has
>   finished; 2. the method LoadImageEx has finished with IfShowFileDialog
>   set to true.

**EDIT** : Some additional code to show how to save the file once the event gets fired.

```
function Dynamsoft_OnGetFilePath(bSave, count, index, path, name) {
    var file_path = path + "\\" + name + ".pdf";
    DWObject.IfShowFileDialog = false;
    DWObject.SaveAsPDF(file_path);
    alert(file_path);
}
```

Comment: Yep you're right - I need to save the file rather than open though

Comment: @TomSelleck I now fully unerstand your last comment. Change first paramater to true so it looks like <input id="btnTest" value="TEST" type="button" onclick="DWObject.ShowFileDialog(true, 'JPG,PNG,TIF', 0, '', '', true, true, 0);"/>  // from documentation - <bool> bsave : true -- show save-file dialog, false -- show open-file dialog.

Comment: Did this help you?

Comment: Hi Hassan - partly, yes. That code is required to set the path, after that - a piece of code needs to be executed to actually save the file to the selected directory..

Comment: @TomSelleck Edited my answer at the bottom to show how to save.